# wifi key masking

Tags: wifi

We currently utilize wifi access in some of our buildings, we are not using RADIUS at this point, but we are using WPA2 with PKI, the issue has recently come up that we want to keep our key private so we generally setup access for our users providing them the wifi key.  The problem is that windows seems to give the option to go back into the wireless properties and unmask the PSK.  We need to resolve this ASAP is there a way to make certain that the PSK remains masked regardless even if your logged in as a local administrator to the machine?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you mean you're using WPA2 with PSK vs. PKI?  I think that's what you meant in your first sentence.

Answer (score 6):

No.  The computer has to have the key to use it.  If a person has administrator access or just  physical access to a computer with that key setup, then find the key.  Hoping for different behavior won't really help you much here.  You should probably consider adjusting your network so that losing this key isn't as big of a problem.

Comment: It's also worth mentioning that even if the client machine could be modified to prevent it from displaying the key, that key can be exposed using other tools, so abandon all hope of obtaining security in that manner.